# Youtube API - Time parameter doesn't work correctly

Tags: time, youtube

I used Youtube API for a long time and its all good, but yesterday I got a bug with Time parameter:

Check this link (without time param): 
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TopGear/uploads?orderby=viewCount&max-results=5

And this link (with time=today): 
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TopGear/uploads?orderby=viewCount&max-results=5&time=today

The contents are the same, and the first entry has:

> 2008-08-17T00:25:36.000Z

So it looks like Youtube server doesn't respond correctly because:

> In a request to retrieve search results, the time parameter restricts
>   the search to videos uploaded within the specified time.
>   (ref: developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?#timesp )

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this too. I have a script that uses this time parameter (set to last_week) and it has been running fine for the past year+. A few days ago the results started including videos from all_time, as if it was ignoring the time parameter entirely. Further investigation on my part shows that right now the 'time' parameter does nothing at all. Something has broke on Google's side.

It might be time to start using v3 of the API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list